# I'm having trouble inserting an image in a TeX file

Tags: graphics

After reading some related question on how to insert an image into a TeX file I tried to do the following:

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \begin{document}
    \section*{a section}
    \subsection*{a subsection}
    some text\
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{vagabon}
    \caption[]{an image}
    \label{fig:vagabon}
    \end{figure}\
    some other text
    \end{document}
```

but the output was:
[image]

with the image before the sections, and not in between the 2 lines of text.
why is that? and what's the proper way to insert an image in the middle of a paragraph?

Comment: Since you have it as a figure, it acts like a float and LaTeX will decide where is the most appropriate position for it. Hence, try `\begin{figure}[!h]`

Comment: This behaviour is by intention. Placing the figures (and tables) to their best place makes the /article/report/book much more readable. You can read more about the mechanism and how to tingle it in Franks answer -> [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017)

Comment: @Johannes: thanks for the link, it provides an awesome explanation, I'll read it carefully and see if I can place the floats where I want them to be

Comment: @azetina: is there an alternative to having it as a figure? I tried this way because it was suggested in other SE questions

Comment: Do you need the `\caption`?

Comment: @Torbjørn: it'd be nice to have it, but if there's a much easier way dropping it then I can do without it!

Comment: You can add `\usepackage{capt-of}` and then use `\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\includegraphics{..}\captionof{figure}{Some fig.\label{stuff}}\end{minipage}`. Another option is to add `\usepackage{float}` and use the `H` float specifier, i.e. `\begin{figure}[H]`, which disables floating. See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: using \figure[H] doesn't render the image, however using \figure[!h] as suggested by azetina works perfectly!

Comment: Not sure why it happens, but I think it moved to the next page.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: you're right, it is moved to the following page, I didn't notice it

Comment: Note that if you don't need the caption, you can just say `\includegraphics[...]{...}` and LaTeX will put the graphic wherever you've said to put it. (This does mean it matters where you say to put it, of course!)

Comment: `[H]` is an undefined option so just prevents the figure being placed anywhere so it goes to the end of the document. If you have a 2014 release and use package `fixltx2e` then you get an error message for undefined options. To define `[H]` meaning "here: do not float" you need the float package.